# add desktop notifications to nodejs+socket .io+ mysql app

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

hope you can help me with this... im working with node socket.io and a database in mysql to push news to 10 or 20 people, we have a simply asp page with a textbox and a button which just insert the message in the database from where the server is querying..... Here is the thing! i need to add desktop notifications to the clients connected to the page with the same information just pushed....

this is how i get news from client.html

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // creamos el websocket con socket.io

        var socket = io.connect('http://mysite:8000');
        // monstramos todos los datos incluidos en #container div
        socket.on('notification', function (data) {
        var registrosList = "";
        $.each(data.registros,function(index,user){
            registrosList += "<div class='media'><div class='media-left'><a><img class='media-object' style='margin-left:4px'; alt='imagen' width='50px' height='50px' src='" + user.link + "'></a></div><div class='media-body'><h5 class='media-heading'>somevariablename <small><i>"+ user.tiempo +"</i></small></h5><p>" + user.user_name +  "</p></div></div> <hr />"
            "" 
                           ; });
        registrosList += "";
        $('#container').html(registrosList);

        $('time').html('Ultimo Update:' + data.time +"<hr>") ;
      });
    </script>
```

this is srv.js

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var app = require('http').createServer(handler),

  io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
  fs = require('fs'),
  mysql = require('mysql'),
  connectionsArray = [],
  connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'mysite',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'myBD',
    dateStrings:true,
    port: 3306
  }),
  POLLING_INTERVAL = 20000,
  pollingTimer;

// if error
connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unles `err` is set)
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});


app.listen(8000);

// html
function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error cargando client.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}



var pollingLoop = function() {

  // query
  var query = connection.query("SELECT registros.idImagen, registros.user_name, registros.user_description, registros.user_img, registros.tiempo, tipomensaje.link, registros.idRegistro FROM registros INNER JOIN tipomensaje ON registros.idImagen = tipomensaje.id ORDER BY registros.idregistro desc LIMIT 5"),

    registros = []; // registros es el array de la query


  query
    .on('error', function(err) {
      // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
      console.log(err);
      updateSockets(err);
    })
    .on('result', function(user) {
      // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
      registros.push(user);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
      if (connectionsArray.length) {

        pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);

        updateSockets({
          registros: registros
        });
      } else {

        console.log('el timer del server se detuvo porque no hay mas conexiones a la aplicacion')

      }
    });
};


// creando un nuevo websocket para mantener el contenido updateado sin  request de ajax
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  console.log('Cant de conexiones:' + connectionsArray.length);
  // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
  if (!connectionsArray.length) {
    pollingLoop();
  }

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
    console.log('socketID = %s got disconnected', socketIndex);
    if (~socketIndex) {
      connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
    }
  });

  console.log('nuevo socket conectado!');
  connectionsArray.push(socket);

});

var updateSockets = function(data) {
  // last update
  data.time = moment().tz('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires').format();

  console.log('pusheando data a los clientes conectados ( cant de conexiones = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
  // sending new data to all the sockets connected
  connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
    tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
  });
};
```

can i send the notification from the admin.asp when i submit the insert to nodejs and there to all clients connected to client.html? how? .... or if there is a way  nodejs can do this job when there is a new insert on the table.. maybe calling [this api](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/10/desktop-notification-like-facebook-using-html5/) showing the last data.

im new with node js and socket.io, im lost right now!

thank you so much!